# How do I change the function of shutdown to sleep in start menu?

Tags: sleep, shutdown, start-menu

I'd like to change the function of shutdown to sleep in start menu. The start menu will show shutdown but upon clicking it the pc will go to sleep. Is it possible?
Also, I'm aware that the power button can be modified but that is not my intent.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1u8e.png

Microsoft Windows 10 Home, Version    10.0.18363 Build 18363

Answer (score 0):

Go to Power Properties and then choose what Power Buttons do.

Set the Power Button to Shut Down and the Sleep Button to Sleep, so that the functions are logical. Then the Windows 10 Start Menu selections will be correct.

I did read your post, but setting these functions correctly sets the Start Menu as well. I have that running properly on both laptops here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to *fully* control shutdown of the PC is to add shortcuts for each possibility. Create batch files, for example, and make shortcuts to them in the start menu, as follows.

- **Shutdown, complete, without delay (but allowing processes to terminate gracefully)**

  ```
  shutdown /s /t 0
  ```
- **Shutdown, complete, without delay and forcing processes to terminate (may cause issues)**

  ```
  shutdown /s /f /t 0
  ```
- **Hibernate, if enabled**

  ```
  shutdown /h
  ```
- To enable a [shortcut to Sleep](https://winaero.com/how-to-sleep-windows-10-from-the-command-line/), though, you'll need a tool such as Microsoft's (well, Sysinternals') *psshutdown.exe*.

If you want to enable and/or disable hibernation, you'll need to run the following as Administrator.

- **Enable hibernation**

  ```
  powercfg -h on
  ```
- **Disable hibernation**

  ```
  powercfg -h off
  ```

Answer (score -1):

You may hide the Shutdown option from the Start Menu by running this `.reg` file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\Start\HideShutDown]
"value"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: My intent was to swap shutdown and sleep function. Something along the lines of using Resource Hacker or a registry edit to, perhaps change the wording of the 2. This used to be possible in XP.

Comment: XP is long gone and I don't think this is possible any more. I think my answer is the next best way to avoid shutdown and is easily undone if required. So why downvote it?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Also i didn't downvote it

Comment: My comment about the downvote was directed to the downvoter. Maybe I should have divided it into two comments.